# Access image metafield inside product.liquid in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I am trying to access image metafield inside the product.liquid template in Shopify.
This is the metafield on a image:

```
{
metafields: [
{
id: 11419631342244,
namespace: "tags",
key: "821753034",
value: "test",
value_type: "string",
description: this is a test,
owner_id: 124682934492,
created_at: "2019-12-23T18:20:58-05:00",
updated_at: "2019-12-23T18:20:58-05:00",
owner_resource: "product_image",
admin_graphql_api_id: "gid://shopify/Metafield/12312423535"
}
]
}
```

I tried accessing it under the `{% for image in product.images %}`
When I access image.alt it returns the result, but when I access image.metafields.namespace['tags'] it returns nothing. I have tried different syntax. If anyone knows how I can access the metafields that will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Don't think you can access image meta fields to liquid.

But you can make use of product meta fields to achieve your goal.create  product metafields with namespace like **"image_metafields"** pass image ID as metafield key and access it using liquid.

[image: Metafiled Created through Metafield Guru Shopify APP]

```
{% assign image_metafields = product.metafields.image_metafields %}

{% assign image_meta_id = "ik_" | append: image.id %}

<p> {{ image_metafields[image_meta_id] }} </p>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped